# How do I change the name of a variable in a fitted glm model?

Tags: r, glm

I have a model object from a model (glm) that someone else built in R.

There are a couple of variables in the model that I would like to re-name. I don't have easy access to re-run their code and build the model with a different variable name in their data frame.

For example, they called a certain variable "previous_customer" and coded it as a dummy variable. But in the data frame I'm using, I have a categorical variable called "previous_customer" and the code we're running needs "previous_customer" to be a categorical variable in a few different places.

I **could** replace previous_customer everywhere in the code that I'm starting with, but I was hoping there was some way to just rename "previous_customer" in the model object I'm working with to something like "previous_customer_flag". If I could do that, it would take me about 2 seconds to handle this problem. However, I'm surprised that I'm not really finding anything on how to rename the variable once a model is built.

Does anyone know how to do this, or if it's not possible for some reason?

Comment: Why do you need it renamed? So the summaries aren't confusing? So that you can easily use the model for predictions?  What is the next step that requires the variable to be renamed?

Comment: The `glm` object will just be a list, so you can probably just find the appropriate elements of the list and reset them manually.  See `?glm`  for details of what the list contains.

Comment: Dason, it is to use the model for predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AndrewGustar is right: your way *can* be done by replacing every instance of the variable name throughout the list. But those names appear in a lot of places, as both character vectors and language objects.

A simpler option would be to write a function wrapped around `predict` which prepares the dataset's columns:

```
predict_with_rename <- function(object, newdata = NULL, ...) {
    if (!is.null(newdata)) {
        newdata[["previous_customer"]] <- newdata[["previous_customer_flag"]]
    }
    predict(object, newdata, ...)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Came across this question when looking for an optimal fix myself.

I ended up using

```
names(model) <- sub("old_name", "new_name", names(model))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you tried and didn't work?

Comment: I tried my code and it did work. So I'm curious to figure out whether there might be a lack of generality in my solution causing it not to work for you. Therefore it would be useful if you could share your particular application and the result.